# Why is this new datetime suddenly not working?

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime

I made a wordpress plugin that displays facebook events (our organisation uses it as a calender thing). a whole bunch of json is returned, which then is translated to a html template.

long story short: I've finished another version, in which I optimized some PHP and split the HTML from the 'core'. I'm replacing all the old versions now (locally using XAMP, to see if anything breaks).

suddenly the page in which I used the plugin doesn't show, at all, not even an error message. I tried several things to print anything to see what was going on, but with no succes.

After isolating the problem (commenting everything bit by bit until I found what caused it) I discovered that the new datetime lines were causes problems:

```
$start_time = new datetime($obj['data'][$x]['start_time'],'G:i');
```

this line has worked for at least a year now, and now all of the sudden it doesn't anymore. Instead I have to do this:

`$start_time = new datetime($obj['data'][$x]['start_time']);
 $start_time->format('G:i');`

this, and other problems, are all of the sudden popping up everywhere, even though both local websites run on php 5.6.15 and wordpress 4.7.2

Does anyone know how this is possible? because it's making my work incredibly frustrating. I think I have about 3 or 4 different custom versions now to make this plugin work, which of course is not what I had intended by splitting the PHP from the HTML templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the class `datetime` nox exists. Be carefull of uppercase letters. The class is calling `DateTime`.

An the second parameter is the Timezone an not the format.

If you would like to create a new DateTime from a specific format use the static method: [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: hmm thanks. The weird thing is that netbeans doesn't mark it as a non-existing class and it works in one of my websites this way....

I'll try to fix it in the 2nd website and put it back in the first website. Hopefully both will work after that

Comment: I fixed some things in the core, but the problem moved to the template, where I used a combination of 'strftime("%A",$upcoming->starting_date->getTimestamp())' and '$upcoming->starting_date->format("d")'. It works across both websites. Now lets hope it holds together on the other websites as well.